# Optimisation of frequent flush()

Tags: java, performance, io, nio, flush

I want to constantly write data to disc.
And I want to flush data to disc frequently (for example every chunk of 64MB). What solution can you propose?

I think standard OutputStream might be a better choice than nio.channels because it is more straightforward.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example (what did you try so far)?

Comment: I tried using nio.channel.write() and force() after each write. Each write is fixed size (for example 64MB). In this moment I am testing performance of FileOutputStream.write() and FileOutputStream.flush()

Comment: When I am using force() after each write performance drop by 60-70%

Comment: Did you have a question? Are you surprised that writing to the disk more often goes slower?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a continuous stream of data, for example appending to the end of a file, regular `OutputStream` with `flush()` called once in a while is just as good or better than `nio`. Where `nio` could give you a big advantage would be writing many small chunks spread over different regions of a file. In that case you could use a memory mapped file and this could be an improvement over old-style writes. However, from the question I understand you are rather dealing with a continuous stream of data. I suggest you implement the regular solution which gives you code you find nicer and only search for alternatives if you find performance lacking. In this case I wouldn't expect `nio` to make noticeable difference.

Comment: I am writing a continuous stream of data to the end of a file in fixed size chunks and at the **same time** I am reading consecutive chunks from other position in file. Both reading and writing are equaly important.

Comment: If you're reading from one place at a time and the accesses are from consecutive positions, you should still be OK with old `io` package.